# get only the second word

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

When i was parsing (simple html dom.php), I encountered the following problem, when receiving the final data, I need to get only the second word(Barcelona) from the given string.

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Taxi Barcelona</h1>
```

On the stack overflow, I found a couple of similar problems, but I would like to analyze this particular case, since using ready-made methods I did not come to success

I already tried this code

```
  $town = $html->find('h1.entry-title', 0);
  $town_name = $town;
  $t_name =  stripos($town_name, ' ');
  echo substr($town_name, 10);
```

But it was unsuccessful for my case because it gave the following line:
"entry-title">Taxi Barcelona

Can anyone lend me a helping hand?

Comment: Aside what @Barmar's answer notes, you are not using `$t_name` anywhere, so the first space offset is never used.

Comment: I guess `10` was supposed to be `$t_name`, as 10 makes no sense there.

Comment: What's the reason for `$town_name = $town;`? Why use another variable for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `innertext` of the element, not use the entire element as a string.

You can use `explode()` to split the string into words.

```
$town_name = $town->innertext();
echo explode(' ', $town_name)[1];
```

Comment: Trailing apostrophe on the second line? @Nafis do take into account cases where there is only one word, where the above would give a warning. (Use e.g. `explode(' ', $town_name)[1] ?? $town_name` that would use the full innertext if the resulting explosion doesn't yield a second word.